# Is there a way to install extensions on VS code Portable?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am actually working with a VS code Portable version and I am looking for install extensions since a day now ! Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I also installed the VS code portable version but the extensions are not automatically loaded (I am not behind a firewall). I assume if you hit menu View -> Extensions you also get nothing loaded from the Marketplace.
However I was able to download a *.vsix file from the internet (csharp-1.16.0-beta4.vsix) and then manually install it: open View -> Extensions the ... opens you a menu -> install from vsix... 
This worked from me - I then watched youtube "Visual Studio Code C# Beginner Tutorial: Hello World that explains the installation steps to make the sample running.
Other extension files (redhat java, go) issued errors when trying to load them.